# Book series involving a stratified society living in giant walled cities

Tags: story-identification, books

- The lower in the city you were, the lower you were in status (even those living under the cities).
- Seemed to be run by Chinese elite.
- There was space travel.
- Issues with implanted mind control.
- Only the elite had gardens and sunlight.
- Lots of issues with food.

As I recall, there were four books. Surprised I didn't keep these very long paperbacks but...

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year/s did you read these books and when do you think they might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about any of the covers?

Comment: How many levels of society were there?  Was level tied to occupation or birth?  What was outside the walls?

Answer (score 6):

I think this is [David Wingrove's Chung Kuo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chung_Kuo_(novel_series)), an eight book series.

> Chung Kuo is primarily set 200 years in the future in mile-high, continent-spanning cities made of a super-plastic called 'ice'. Housing a global population of 40 billion, the cities are divided into 300 levels and success and prestige is measured by how far above the ground one lives.

Other points:

- Society was run by Chinese elites and, yes, only elites had access to things like gardens and sunlight
- There was space travel
- There were issues with food supply

I don't recall anything specific about mind control.

Comment: I agree this is a good guess.  I wasn't sure, though, that's why I asked about the walls.